# MS Sql Server: Trailing spaces and disk space in a varchar column in a table

Tags: sql-server, whitespace, space, varchar, trailing

Does removing trailing spaces in a Varchar column values save any disk space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does. Might not be very much. But every one of those trailing spaces the computer has to store so removing those will free up space.